# Word for someone who's incompetent

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Here's the idea I'm trying to convey: "He was by far the least proficient in his class."

Here's the sentence I want to use: "He was the (slacker) of the group." Except that "slacker" sounds a bit wrong for what I'm trying to say. Is there a better noun that would fit here?

Comment: Are you trying to stick with a more casual, slangy feel to the sentence, as "slacker" would imply, or a more formal representation?

Comment: Hm... I think either would work.

Comment: What kind of class/group?

Comment: Here, *incompetent* is the only word that fits properly. If *stupid* were not such a common derogatory term, that would have been a good option as well.

Comment: You need to elaborate more on what you're trying to say. _Slacker_ implies poor performance due to laziness. _Least proficient_ implies the person may have worked hard, but simply didn't have the ability to succeed. Which are you trying to convey? @Kris: The "only" word? That's a strong assertion. That said, _incompetent_ is a very promising candidate.

Comment: @JR Amended: "Only word **I could find so far** that... "

Comment: Sorry, should've specified that the noun should mean "least proficient". Slacker was just the first word that came to mind, even though it's not perfect for what I'm trying to say. And it's just a class of students.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"underachiever", "boat anchor", "doorstop" all have varying degrees of negativity and rudeness but what might also play a role in your choice of word, of course, is whether this person's performance has any affect on you and the class.  If the person is just not trying and is lazy, as *slacker* implies, a derogatory word such as "gold bricker", "dead-beat", "goof-off", "loafer", "slouch", "sloth", "back-slider" or "lazybones" could also work. (per www.thesaurus.com)

Answer (score 4):

What about deadbeat, idler or loafer

Answer (score 3):

*Slacker* implies laziness, so that may or may not be a good word for what you want.  If this is a matter of *ability* rather than *motivation*, then I like Kris' suggestion of *incompetent* instead.

Another word you might consider is *inept*.  The words *unskilled* or *bumbling* might work, too, but they suggest a shortcoming in dexterity more than intelligence (such words might work well in a trade school, though, for the situation you describe).  If you want to emphasize results (or a lack thereof), you might try *unproductive*.

Yet another way to express this sentiment is to forgo the synonym, and instead opt for one of the many catch phrases used to humorously describe the shortcomings of individuals in relation to their peers, such as:

> *Not the sharpest knife in the drawer.*
>   *Not the sharpest tack on the board.*
>   *Not the sharpest tool in the shed.*
>   *Not the brightest crayon in the box.*
>   *Not the brightest bulb on the tree.*

although some of these might be considered trite.

Comment: +1 Yes, even I had these questions: 'If this is a matter of ability rather than motivation'.

Answer (score 2):

You might say “He was *[hindmost](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hindmost)* in the group.”  Hindmost means the most to the rear.  Or say “On a good day, he was last in his class.”

If you want to laud a person's effort, even if he fared badly in a course, you might say something like “In spite of being  worst-prepared and most-disadvantaged at the outset of the course, and in spite of always faring last, he stuck with it and was not among the many who flunked out.”

Comment: @tchrist, question doesn't indicate what slant is desired.  However, I've added a more-positive paragraph

Comment: Of his classmates he had the most room for improvement.

Answer (score 2):

You could say:

> He was the **dunce** of the group.

[dunce](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dunce?show=0&t=1349548196):

> a slow-witted or stupid person

Answer (score 1):

You could say he was the *laggard of the class*, the *class laggard*, or (slang) that he *brought* or *brings up the rear.*

Answer (score 1):

> He was the ***_*____** of the group. (least proficient)

Besides the suggestions of *laggard* and _incompetent, I would also consider one of:

1. slowcoach/slowpoke
2. bungler
3. blunderer
4. dawdler
5. sluggard
6. klutz
7. greenhorn/amateur
8. also-ran
9. flunker/flunkee
10. dud
11. non-starter

I think that some additional context would have provided the OP with more signal and less noise. What class/group are we talking about? A proficiency for what exactly? etc.

Comment: +1 For _dud_; it was one of the first words that came to my mind. (Also like the _blunderer_, _dawdler_, and _sluggard_)

Answer (score 1):

You could also say that he was the **weakest** in the class if you're wanting to not state strongly as to *why* they're in that position. In the same vein you could say that they were the **least competent** or **worst** ?

Answer (score 0):

You could call him a **couch potato, clock-watcher, lazybones, or a loafer**.

**Gold brick** is another term that is *informally* used in AmE.