# Idiom for someone who needs constant babysitting

Tags: idioms

I work in an I.T. company and I was assigned to work with a lazy guy who needs constant baby sitting. For instance, yesterday he asked me to go to his desk because he could not type the "@" symbol.

In Spanish we have an idiom that says : "He got drown in a glass of water". Which means he gets stuck and in minor or dumb things.

What's the most similar idiom in English?

Comment: Not an idiom... **spoon-feeding** came to mind. Best of luck to you with that guy.

Comment: Related: [word for someone who's incompetent](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84881/synonym-for-slacker/84905#84905).

Comment: _Very_ closely related (but far fewer examples): ['A few bricks short of a hod' – what is the name for this type of saying?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/473369/a-few-bricks-short-of-a-hod-what-is-the-name-for-this-type-of-saying/473390#473390).

Comment: Isn't "needs constant babysitting" the idiom you need?

Answer (score 3):

You can say he's 'high-maintenance'. https://www.macmillanthesaurus.com/high-maintenance

Answer (score 3):

The English language has numerous idioms comparable to *'he would drown in a glass of water'*¹. Some examples:

- They're dumber than a bag of hammers (*aka* dumb as a box of
  rocks).
- They're not the sharpest knife in the drawer.
- They're not the brightest light in the harbor.
- They're a few    screws short of a hardware store.
- They're about as sharp as a    marble.
- Their elevator doesn't go all the way to the top    floor.
- Their lights are on but nobody's home.
- Their IQ    would make a good golf score.
- They couldn't pour water out of a    boot that had instructions on
  the heel.
- Their driveway doesn't    quite reach the road.
- Their antenna doesn't pick up all the    channels.
- They're proof that evolution is reversible.
- They're running on 3 cylinders.
- Their engine is running but    nobody is behind the wheel.
- If you gave them a penny for their    thoughts, you'd get
  change.
- It's hard to believe they beat out    100 million other
  spermatozoa.
- If evolution was an experiment,    their ancestors were in the
  control group.
- They would be unarmed    in a battle of wits.
- They're not rowing with both oars.
- Their phone's connected but there's no dial tone.
- They're an    open book but the pages are blank.
- If they had a brain they'd be    on the floor playing with it.
- If brains were dynamite, they    couldn't blow their nose.
- If they were any slower they'd need to    be watered once a
  week.
- They couldn't hit the floor if they fell    on it.

Some of those were shamelessly stolen from (and there's more at) the [Not Too Bright list](https://dan.hersam.com/lists/not_bright.html).

---

¹ <sub>Your original example would seem to have an international circulation as I've heard it in EN-CA at least.</sub>

Comment: LOL! These are funny! Haven't heard of any of them.

Comment: I've often thought this site could use an injection of a little humour now and again. Thanks!

Comment: Not all of these signify that someone needs constant care, though. Mostly these are idioms for the 'they' being dull-witted, impractical, etc. (But they do seem to be synonymous to the example used by the OP).